# Recording the Order of Clicks in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've an array of colors initially `['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']`, it is shuffled to, lets say, `["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"]`.

Now, I've interactive boxes where the user can click on these boxes.

The first element of the shuffled array is shown through a `for` loop and I now want to prompt the user to click on a box, if it matches this color, it is 'right' and want to continue the loop if not, it is 'wrong' and want to pause the loop till he clicks the right color box.

I want this to go throughout the box until all the colors have been correctly identified.

I'm not able to figure out the code for writing the above statements.

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2cbcpq2r/2/ to get a clear idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm not able to figure out how I'm going to record the click events based on the current given to me.

Comment: I think the question is not phrased good enough..

Comment: I've tried to phrase the question better. @Regent But, I want the `click` to check based on the current element of the shuffled array.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep you shuffled array of colors. What about boxes? Should they always have the same order of colors, or should their colors be shuffled as well, but in different order?

Comment: @Regent Which is why I attached a fiddle. Yes, they remain at the same position.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cbcpq2r/5/)?

Comment: @Regent Yes, it was something of that sort that I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var counter = 0;
var colorArr = ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'];
$('div.box').click(function(){        
    if(this.className.indexOf(colorArr[counter])!=-1)
        counter++;
    else
        alert('wrong');
    if(counter==colorArr.length)
        alert('success');
});
```

change your html file as

```
<div class="box blue" id="b1"></div>
<div class="box green" id="b2"></div>
<br>
<div class="box yellow" id="b3"></div>
<div class="box red" id="b4"></div>
<br>
<div class="disp" id="disp"></div>
```

**NOTE:** If you dont want to add class , then use name attribute in html.

where colorArr is the correct order of color array

I created a counter which tracks success count

If the user passed all clicks success alert is shown

If the user clicked wrong color then wrong alert is shown

HOPE IT HELPS

Comment: But I get your idea. It's nice. I think I can get around with a few modifications. :)

Comment: If the code works, give a tick. If it helps in solving your problem, give a vote up. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Some work around in `html` and `jQuery`

Try this

```
$('div.box').on('click', function() {
    alert(currColor);
    if($(this).hasClass(currColor)) {
        alert('right');
    } else {
       alert('wrong');
    }  
});
```

**[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cbcpq2r/8/)**

Comment: 1. inline JS is outdated. Furthermore, I don't see any point to use both normal event handler and inline JS for same elements. 2. I suppose showing box color (if it is incorrect box) is not what OP wants. 3. Why only one color is required to click?